# Reacjs / TypeScript : Custom HTMLATTRIBUTES => Declared as a INT but shown in the DOM as a "STRING"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

sorry for my terrible English.

I am trying to build an app in ReactJS + Typesctript ... and it is completly HELL.

In a component `TABS`, I declared 2 customs HTMLATTRIBUTES :

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    **playerid?: number;**
    component?: string;
  }
};
```

The Tabs component is used like this logic :

```
  <Tabs>   
      {
          tabList.map(tab => (
              <Tab 
                  component={tab.component} 
                  **playerid={player.id}**
                  key={tab.id}
                  title={tab.label}
                  icon={tab.icon}
                  name={tab.name}
                  selected>

              </Tab>
          )) 
      }       
  </Tabs>
```

The < Tab > Component has thoses params declared :

```
type Params = {
    title: string;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    icon: string;
    selected?: boolean;
    name:string;
    **playerid:number;**
    component:string;
}
```

And finally i render in the < Tabs >

```
 childrenArray.map(child => (
                        
      React.isValidElement(child) ? 
          <li 
              component={child.props.component}
              playerid= {Number(child.props.playerid)}
              className={`${child.props.name} ${((child.props.name === tabActive) && "is-active")?"is-active":""}`} 
              onClick = { (e: React.MouseEvent) => ChangeActiveTab(e)} 
              key={child.key}>    
              
              <a>
                <span className="icon is-small"><i className={`fa ${child.props.icon}`}></i></span>
                <span>{child.props.title}</span>
              </a>
          </li> : 0
  ))
```

When i check the code HTML on Chrone Inspector :

```
<ul>
    <li component="biography" **playerid="1"** class="tabBio is-active">
      <a>
        <span class="icon is-small"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></span>
        <span>Biographie</span>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

PLAYERID is a String !  why ? how can I fix it ?

Thanks for helping, I hope i was clear enought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All** HTML attributes are enclosed in quotes `"`, including numeric values like `height` and `width`.  This means that there is no distinction between a `number` and a `string` in the HTML code.  If you want to extract the value from an `e.currentTarget`, you have to cast it to a `number` yourself using `parseInt`.